# Updating from Spring Security 2.0 to Spring Security 3.2.9

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have updated my `security-sso-beans.xml` to the below code when migrating from Spring Security 2.0.2 to Spring Security 3.2.9. I am getting access denied error and JSON-error creating beans. Can you please guide if the file is incorrect.

```xml
<sec:http pattern="/webcontent/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/redirect.jsp" security="none"/>
       
<sec:http entry-point-ref="entryPoint" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
           <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied.atps"/>
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/home.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUBMITTER,ROLE_FINANCE_DIRECTOR,ROLE_INVOICE_POINT_APPROVER,ROLE_REGIONAL_DIRECTOR,ROLE_TP_REVIEWER,ROLE_INVOICE_POINT,ROLE_TECH_OPS,ROLE_MARKET, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CAA,ROLE_OPEL_APPROVER')"/>
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myrole.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUBMITTER,ROLE_FINANCE_DIRECTOR,ROLE_INVOICE_POINT_APPROVER,ROLE_REGIONAL_DIRECTOR,ROLE_TP_REVIEWER,ROLE_INVOICE_POINT,ROLE_TECH_OPS,ROLE_MARKET,ROLE_OPEL_APPROVER')" />
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/f1/*.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUBMITTER,ROLE_FINANCE_DIRECTOR,ROLE_INVOICE_POINT_APPROVER,ROLE_REGIONAL_DIRECTOR,ROLE_TP_REVIEWER,ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CAA,ROLE_OPEL_APPROVER')" />
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/grid.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUBMITTER,ROLE_FINANCE_DIRECTOR,ROLE_INVOICE_POINT_APPROVER,ROLE_REGIONAL_DIRECTOR,ROLE_TP_REVIEWER,ROLE_INVOICE_POINT,ROLE_TECH_OPS,ROLE_MARKET,ROLE_OPEL_APPROVER')" />
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CAA')" />
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/adminGrid/*.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CAA')" />
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/form/handledraft.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUBMITTER,ROLE_TP_REVIEWER')" />
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/form/handleTPRequest.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUBMITTER,ROLE_TP_REVIEWER')" />
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/form/handleDistributorRequest.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUBMITTER,ROLE_TP_REVIEWER')" />
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/userreport.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CAA')" />
           <sec:intercept-url pattern="/caa.atps" access="hasRole('ROLE_CAA')" />
           <sec:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="authFilter" />
           <sec:session-management>
               <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1"/>
           </sec:session-management>
           <sec:logout/>
</sec:http>
```

Comment: Are you really have an application with Spring Security 2.0,2? That version is more than 14 years old. Why you are only updating to 3.2.9? This version is 9 years old.

Comment: Yes . The application is old . upgrading to more latest version of spring is causing lots of compatibility issues and many changes to the codebase . We need to upgrade to java 8 which is why I am upgrading to the 3.2.9 version which is compatible. Earlier we were using java 6 and spring 2.0.2